# ldd weirdness on old binaries

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ldd

I got the following weirdness with ldd

```
$ sudo ldd ./monit 
    not a dynamic executable

$ readelf -d monit 

Dynamic section at offset 0x25ea90 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpam.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libresolv.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnsl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...

$ file ./monit 
./monit: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.0, with debug_info, not stripped

$ uname -r -i -m
4.15.0-43-generic x86_64 x86_64


$ file $(which ls)
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9567f9a28e66f4d7ec4baf31cfbf68d0410f0ae6, stripped
```

the other binaries and libraries are compiled against more recent kernel/system and ldd succeeded in reporting the shared libraries, I'm wondering if there are any incompatibilities between different environment despite of the fact that the binaries are built on the same architecture.. 
Another stupid question if some of the shared libraries would be upgraded like libpam, there would be chances that the binaries won't run without interposing the old libraries, is it likely that the api will be change so much? if the new releases was backward compatible, wouldn't be enough making a new dynamic link (ln) to the old name?

-- latest  --
What a f.. idiot. I forgot that I had denied the execution privilige of the partition on that host :( 
The ldd command works as expected

Comment: Why the sudo in that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I tried also without sudo, I can't do further test at the moment, I will try again tonight
  thanks

Comment: You don't state the problem. What is the weird behavior?

Comment: I expected to get the dynamic libraries list (shown by readelf) in the ldd output

Comment: @Shawn Got the same error message without sudo

Answer (score 0):

> if there are any incompatibilities between different environment despite of the fact that the binaries are built on the same architecture

The "environment" on which the program is dependent is a big word for many small things put together. It is an architecture (ie. cpu supported instruction set) or like, well, an architecture (motherboard structure, cpu to mem structure, etc.) or like operating system specifics (ex. POSIX compliant system with GNU extensions or  DOS system with dos.h libraries). Environment are also libraries versions, as they're api can change, and also like environmental variables (well, if such exists in the environment).

The *know* "if there are any incompatibilities between different environment" you would have to inspect all the changes between two version by hand. People use versioning as the reliable and poor way of informing, that something changed. Then, you have go to documentation, to see what changed in human readable way. Then you have to go to the source code, to see what really changed.

> if some of the shared libraries would be upgraded like libpam, there would be chances that the binaries won't run without interposing the old libraries, is it likely that the api will be change so much?

First of all note that most of unix programs are under GNU license that says:

> THERE IS NO WARRANTY FOR THE PROGRAM

No one will ever warranty that it will work in any case. That said, it may. It may not. There is so much different libraries in the world and they are written by different people and they all change the api so often, it may not work. It may work. It depends.

To be sure that api doesn't change that much, smart people wrote to [standards](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). And [standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). And [standards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2017). And standards....

On the other side are people, developers, that do all that hard work *for free*. They need to change the api, so to introduce a new nice feature or fix a bug. So they change api a bit. And this can break old programs, that dependent on that api.

> if the new releases was backward compatible, wouldn't be enough making a new dynamic link (ln) to the old name?

I did that more often than I would like to admit (mostly to run eagle with old libpng) and most often it works. Just try it, (normally, under normal unix, run as user, with good permissions) the worst thing that can happen is that your program will segfault (well, the worst that can happen under sudo is a permanent damage to your hardware and erasure of all your data).

Most (not all) GNU/Linux systems use glibc as the implementation of the C standard library. This should be the most stable api, as all C programs depend on it. And it [changes too](https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=timeline&l=glibc) and it is not always backwards compatible too.

Comment: thanks for the exhaustive answer. But I don't get why readelf has shown the shared libraries list whereas ldd has given the warning message. 
Anyway what I need is locking the monit release to a stable tested version, letting upgrade its shared libraries if possible. 
If I used a package manager excluding monit from the upgrade it would lock its dependencies upgrade.
Maybe the best strategies is avoiding the shared libraries at all and recompile it statically...

Comment: People use [docker](https://github.com/umputun/monit-docker) nowadays, since it's easier to setup than static compilation. If you can, go with static compilation. If you are bound to a specific monit version working with a specific kernel version, setup a virtual machine just for it. `package manager excluding monit` - if you upstream doesn't give you updated packages, you can recompile it (it's linux after all). [monit](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/commits/all) looks updated.

Comment: After I had answered you, I realized that I was launching the ldd command from a partition without the execution grants..  I rebound it with the right privileges and now ldd works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time and usefull hints